# Does 'forever' log file include both STDOUT and STDERR content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I'm running a process via [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), however I'm confused about the usage of `-l`, `-o` and `-e` options.

From the documentation:

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

Can someone confirm if the output to `LOGFILE (-l)` includes both stdout & stderr, along with forever messages (e.g. 'retarting forever').

If so, am I right in assuming that `-o` and `-e` are there ONLY if you want to send your stdout/stderr to different locations; and if you want everything in one log file `-l` is the only option you need to specify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the `-l LOGFILE` option generates a log file with the combined output of forever, stdOut & stdErr from the child process.

I wish there was a way to have just the forever output be logged to this file if you use the `-o OUTFILE` and `-e ERRFILE` options because it seems like duplication.

Answer (score 0):

`forever start script.js`

↓

`forever logs script.js -f`